# Find matches between two arrays in EJS

Tags: express, ejs, knex.js

I am using node, express, knex, postgres, EJS, and bootstrap.  I have one table, deckorderfil, that has a primary key column of ordnbr.  My other table, decktowfil, has a foreign key of ordnbr referencing deckorderfil.

My problem I am running into is that I cannot seem to get EJS to only print those decktowfil results that match deckorderfil.

I have successfully figured out how to have both results show up after a GET request is made to a url by doing the following:

My index.js route:

```
router.get('/dashboard', authMiddleware.ensureLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  Tow.getTows().then(tows => {
    Job.getJobs().then(jobs => {
    jobs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jobs)); //deckorderfil table
    tows = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tows)); //decktowfil table
    res.render('dashboard', { title: 'Express', jobs: jobs, tows: tows });
  });
    });
});
```

my dashboard.ejs:

```
<% for (let i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) { %> <!-- deckorderfil (primary key) table -->
  <%= jobs[i].ordnbr %>
  <% } %>

<% for (let j = 0; j < tows.length; j++) { %> <!-- decktowfil (foreign key) table -->
    <%= tows[j].ordnbr %>

  <% } %>
```

dashboard.ejs prints the following:

```
D1 D2 D3 (the jobs ordnbr's) D1 D1 D2 (the tows ordnbr's)
```

My question is, how do I create an IF statement that says, "if the job ordnbr is D1, only return the tows ordnbr's that also equal D1, and create divs for each of these"?

I have already succeeded in looping my EJS to produce divs that show each deckorderfil ID and its other variables.  I am trying to embed the matching decktowfil records within those divs as their own individual divs.  Here is a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Should I do this by way of Knex, EJS, or jquery/javascript? And if so, where and at what point? I have thus far tried to set the id of the parent element in my HTML to the deckorderfil ordnbr and then match my EJS query to that, but it has not worked.

Thank you and please let me know if you need anything else to answer the question.

Comment: Your naming conventions are making this really difficult, so help me out here. Is `jobs` referring to `deckorderfil` and `tows` referring to `decktowfil`? Also, what is the shape of the `jobs` and `tows` you are passing in? Like, what key/value pairs are present.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear.  I added comments to help understand.  Yes you are correct.  For deckorderfil (jobs) the primary key is ordnbr and it has a serial column for order_id. For decktowfil (tows) the foreign key is ordnbr REFERENCES deckorderfil (ordnbr), and it has a serial column for tow_id. @DanielSchroederDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work.  It was all about trying to figure out how to nest the for loops and getting the divs right.

Here is how I structed my EJS to get the right output.  I did not need to use a .find() operator.

```
<% for (let i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="outer">
    <p>Jobs <%= jobs[i].ordnbr %></p>
    <% for (let j = 0; j < tows.length; j++) { %>
        <% if (tows[j].ordnbr === jobs[i].ordnbr) { %>
            <div class="inner">
                <p>Tow: <%= tows[j].tow_id %></p>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    <% } %>
```

Thank you Daniel for your help.  You sparked my ingenuity.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact shape of the objects, here is a way to implement this that would work:

**Express app**

```
const jobs = [
  {
    orderNum: 'D1'
  },
  {
    orderNum: 'D2'
  },
  {
    orderNum: 'D3'
  },
];

const tows = [
  {
    orderNum: 'D1',
    orders: [
      1,
      2,
      3,
    ],
  },
  {
    orderNum: 'D2',
    orders: [
      1,
      2,
      3,
    ],
  },
  {
    orderNum: 'D3',
    orders: [
      1,
      2,
      3,
    ],
  },
];

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index', { jobs, tows });
});
```

**Index.ejs***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .outer {
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding: 18px;
        margin: 12px;
      }
      .inner {
        margin: 12px;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <% for (let i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) { %>
      <div class="outer">      
        <p>Jobs<%= jobs[i].orderNum %></p>
          <% tows.find(tow => tow.orderNum === jobs[i].orderNum).orders.forEach(order => { %>
          <div class="inner">

            <p>Tows: id <%= order %></p>

          </div>
          <% }); %>
      </div>
    <% } %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond!  I'm going to try and implement this and get back to you.  Seems like I would need to somehow get the 'tows' data from my table into the format you suggested.  Any suggestions as to how I might do that?  I'm using knex, so my knex query looks like this: getTows: function() { return knex('decktowfil');

Comment: Unfortunately I tried your solution and I could not figure it out.  When I tried exactly as you posted it did not work either.  Any other ideas?